# Проблемы с циклом c++

Tags: c++, циклы, while

Задача заключается в следующем:

[image: Условие]

Решить нужно обязательно с использованием постусловия.
Написал следующее:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;



int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    float a, b, c, x, xn, xk, dx, y, z;
    float const Pi = 3.1415;
    cout << "Введите a, b, c, xn, xk, dx \n";
    cin >> a >> b >> c >> xn >> xk >> dx;
    x = xn;
    do {
        if (x < 5)
            if (a * x + 1 >= 0) {
                z = cbrt(a * x + 1) + b;
            }
            else cout << "x= "<<x<<"Не выводится из-под корня"<<endl;

        if (x == 5) z = sin((b * x + 2) * Pi / 180);
        if (x > 5) z = b * cos((c * x + 3) * Pi / 180);

        y = (sqrt(z) + b * cos(z * Pi / 180)) / log(z * x);

        cout << "x=" <<setw(3)<<setprecision(2) << x <<" y="<<setw(3)<<setprecision(2)<<y<< endl;


        x = x + dx;

    } while (x >= xk);

    system("pause");
    return(0);
}
```

Есть следующие проблемы:

1. Когда срабатывает условие "Не выводится из-под корня" программа прекращает свою работу, видимо из-за того, что невозможно вычисление y. Хотелось бы, чтобы в таблицу консоли просто фиксировалось, что при x= таком-то не выводится из-под корня.
2. Проблема с сами циклом, когда на ввод даю положительный x, который гарантированно не вызовет проблем, программа делает только одну итерацию. Задаю xn = 0, а xk= 4, но итерация происходит только одна.
3. Вроде бы, для возможности вычисления y необходимо добавить следующие условия:

```
if (sqrt(z) < 0) cout << "Не выводится из-под корня";
else if (z * x < 0) cout << "Невозможно вычислить логарифм";
else if (z * x == 0) cout << "Деление на ноль";
else y = (sqrt(z) + b * cos(z * Pi / 180)) / log(z * x);
```

Но это не точно... Однако как это прикрутить, когда и так ничего не работает, для меня загадка.

В общем и целом в результате в консоли должна быть небольшая табличка со значениями y при соответствующих значениях x.

Comment: `while (x >= xk)` -  что это условие должно делать?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy запускать цикл заново, пока x не станет больше или равен xk

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy так, эту проблему я понял, спасибо...

Comment: [Уильям Кэхэн](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%8D%D1%85%D1%8D%D0%BD,_%D0%A3%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%8F%D0%BC_%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD) ещё жив. Но когда он умрёт, не сомневаюсь, его дух будет регулярно спускаться на Землю и терзать всех тех кто без надобности использует `float`, и с удвоенной силой тех, кто указывает Пи с точностью, недостаточной даже для `float`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy мне для дальнейшей проверки нужно будет вводить в программу дроби, разве это неоправданное использование? А объявление числа Пи я переписал с примера преподавателя...

Comment: Всегда используйте для вычислений `double`. Всегда берите Пи из стандартной библиотеки, если его там нет, то используйте значение с двадцатью знаками после запятой: `3.14159265358979323846`. Прошу вас критически относится к тому что говорит преподаватель. И говорят на этом сайте. И я.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy спасибо, я понял, почитаю про double. Но тут, к сожалению, ограничен требованиями к оформлению

Comment: `float` - требование преподавателя?

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy ну, он четко проговорил, что за несоответствия в подобных моментах будут сниматься баллы. Мол, на первых парах повторяйте, думать будете потом. Человек довольно упертый, в возрасте, ничего не поделаешь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это пример вычислений в цикле с контролем ошибок и печатью сообщений. Вычисление разбиты на этапы. Каждый этап или вычисляет значение или оставляет описание ошибки в переменной `error`. Если переменная `error` уже установлена, все следующие этапы пропускаются:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const double x1 = -2;
    const double x2 = 4;
    const double dx = 0.25;
    double x = x1;

    do {
        const char *error = nullptr;

        double ln_x; // ln(x)

        if (error == nullptr) {
            if (x > 0) {
                ln_x = log(x);
            } else {
                error = "логарифм отрицательного числа или нуля";
            }
        }

        double y; // y = 1 / ln(x)

        if (error == nullptr) {
            if (ln_x != 0) {
                y = 1. / ln_x;
            } else {
                error = "деление на ноль";
            }
        }

        cout << "x =" << fixed << setw(5) << setprecision(2) << x << "  ";
        if (error == nullptr) {
            cout << " y =" << setw(5) << setprecision(2) << y << '\n';
        } else {
            cout << ' ' << error << '\n';
        }

        x += dx;
    } while (x <= x2);
}
```

> ```
> $ g++ tabulation.cpp 
>
> $ ./a.out
> x =-2.00   логарифм отрицательного числа или нуля
> x =-1.75   логарифм отрицательного числа или нуля
> x =-1.50   логарифм отрицательного числа или нуля
> x =-1.25   логарифм отрицательного числа или нуля
> x =-1.00   логарифм отрицательного числа или нуля
> x =-0.75   логарифм отрицательного числа или нуля
> x =-0.50   логарифм отрицательного числа или нуля
> x =-0.25   логарифм отрицательного числа или нуля
> x = 0.00   логарифм отрицательного числа или нуля
> x = 0.25   y =-0.72
> x = 0.50   y =-1.44
> x = 0.75   y =-3.48
> x = 1.00   деление на ноль
> x = 1.25   y = 4.48
> x = 1.50   y = 2.47
> x = 1.75   y = 1.79
> x = 2.00   y = 1.44
> x = 2.25   y = 1.23
> x = 2.50   y = 1.09
> x = 2.75   y = 0.99
> x = 3.00   y = 0.91
> x = 3.25   y = 0.85
> x = 3.50   y = 0.80
> x = 3.75   y = 0.76
> x = 4.00   y = 0.72
> ```